# Link to Google Play Store with custom parameter

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to build a link to Play Store (to my application) with a custom parameter? I would like to be able to read this parameter in my app after installation.
I have found Firebase Dynamic Links but it does not seem to support such functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the campaign measurement links.

Link generator:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder

You can read the params that you define by implementing your own BroadcastReceiver instead of using com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.

There in your receiver you can do something like this to get all the params defined in your link.

```
   public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
              //You will find all of your params under the extra "referrer" like:

              String referrer = extras.getString("referrer");

              //Then you only have to parse it and get the param you need.

            }
       }
   }
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar solution for iOS?

Comment: Check if the ios version of GA helps:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns